# Remove dynamically generated string from tag value jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, dynamic

I have a code that looks like the below where I want to remove string that is dynamically created on page load:

```
<nav id="navtop"> Dynamically generated text here 
<ul><li>Item 1</li><li>Item 2</li>...</ul></nav>
```

The question is how I can remove this string "Dynamically generated text here" (which was generated dynamically by script on page load) from the  tag text value?

I am thinking of using this code but it did not do the trick:

```
var str = "dynamic text";
var $holder = $('#navtop');
var value = $holder.text();
if(value == str){
$holder:contains(str).remove();

$( "value:contains('dynamic text')" ).remove();
```

any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you want to get rid of all text nodes immediately under `#navtop`, you can use `$('#navtop').contents().filter(function() { this.nodeType == 3; }).remove();`.

Comment: do you want to remove the lists under `nav` or just the text ?

Comment: Can you give a more clearer example with what is the value to be removed

Comment: @ArunPJohny I mean the value is the same string that is before <ul> tag which is "Dynamically generated text here "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First store content of `ul` in a temporary variable:

```
var inside = $("#navtop ul").clone();
```

The use this code:

```
 $("#navtop").html(inside);
```

[Here is a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kjLy4bhu/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following -

```js
var ulText = $('#navtop ul').text();
var navText = $('#navtop').text();
var textToRemove = navText.substring(0, navText.indexOf(ulText));


$('div').html(textToRemove);

$('#navtop2').html($("#navtop2").html().replace(textToRemove, ''));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Original DOM:
<nav id="navtop">Dynamically generated text here
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>...</ul>
</nav>

Text to remove:
<div></div>

<br/>
<br/>After removing dynamic text:

<nav id="navtop2">Dynamically generated text here
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>...</ul>
</nav>

<span></span>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but unfortunately that does not answer the question because the code is just replacing text, whilst the question is aimed to remove dynamically generated text before <ul> tag inside <nav> tag.

Comment: I don't see any difference.. Replacing text (i.e. string) with an empty string should do the same thing and shouldn't impact your DOM (I think).. Did you actually try the code? What happens then?